# C++ array value sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

If I want to sort the second dimension's 0 element like that:

```
short arr[5];

arr[0][0] = 122;
arr[0][1] = 33;
arr[0][2] = 45;

arr[1][0] = 33;
arr[1][1] = 12;
arr[1][2] = 42;
.
.
.
```

It will sort `arr[i][0]`, but `arr[i][1]` and `arr[i][2]` will come with `arr[i][0]` to a new element.

Comment: Use a C++ `vector<>` rather than a C-style array - then you can just apply the `sort` method. If you *must* use C-style arrays for some reason then use `qsort()` from `cstdlib` to sort.

Comment: @Paul:  `sort` is a generic non-member function algorithm.  It can be used with an array just as easily as it can be used with a `vector`.

Comment: You declared a one-dimensional array and are accessing it as a two-dimensional array?  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: can you list (add to the question) what the output was for the 2x3 example and what the desired output is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you : 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 6):

To sort a standard C array using the `std::sort` algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>
    ...
    sort(&arr[0], &arr[0] + 5)
```

Now if you have a two dimensional array, you can use the same idea to sort the second dimension of each item in the first dimension:

```
short arr[5][5];
...
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
   sort(&arr[i][0], &arr[i][0] + 5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::sort` will, by default, sort objects in ascending order.  To sort in descending order, you can use the `std::greater` function object:

```
std::sort(arr, arr + 5, std::greater<short>());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are too many sorting algorithms, like quicksort and bubble sort, with different complexity. And this complexity varies upon size of data set, default order of data within data set, etc. You have to study your data set and pick one algorithm that will meet your requirement faster. You can find sorting algorithms in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm.

Comment: Given that the standard library has `sort` (average case N log N) and `stable_sort` (worst case N (log N)^2), there is _very rarely_ a good reason to implement your own sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a homework assignment, you probably don't want to use `std::sort`. Your teacher might consider you cheeky :P

I'd go with what Muhit said and try learning from Wikipedia's article on sorting algorithms, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm. Most of the individual articles have the algorithms implemented in pseudocode, so you can just pick one to code up.

But if this is for a different project, yeah, definitely go with [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), there shouldn't really be any reason to code up a sorting algorithm by hand right now.